# Finding and editing multiple links with jquery

Tags: jquery, href

Ok guys, I have a bit of code that needs editing. I have tried some different php but it is not working so maybe some jquery stud can figure this out.

Here is the code.

```
<li class="message_sharing_facebook greyback_primary_accent"> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://123.456.789.101/~user/file.php" target="_blank">F</a> </li>
<li class="message_sharing_twitter greyback_primary_accent"> <a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=http://123.456.789.101/~user/file.php" target="_blank">T</a> </li>
```

I am wanting to find each instance of "http://123.456.789.101/~user" replace it with "MyUrl.com and keep the file.php at the end.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Please give an example of what you want the output to be.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$("li > a").each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace("http://123.456.789.101/~user", "myurl.com");
});
```

You can see it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gABzm/).

The idea is that for [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) anchor found directly under an `li` you are going to replace the URL you provided with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

```
[].forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="http://123.456.789.101/~user"]'),
    function(el){
        el.href = el.href.replace('http://123.456.789.101/~user','myurl.com')
     }
);
```

Just wanted to provide a pure js option.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/24jM4/)**